# Can't erase a dir with rmtree because it is being used by another process

Tags: python, pywin32, shutil

I am trying to erase a entire directory with all it content with `rmtree` but I am getting the following exception:

> [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

the folder that I am trying to erase have some word docs that were opened with win32com.client above in the code, my code to erase is:

```
shutil.rmtree('destinationFolder')
```

I also tried to erase every file at once iterating throw the files of the folder and then `os.remove` but it doesn't work either, throwing the same error.

Comment: A process either has a file open in that directory or subdirectory, or a process may its current directory set to a directory or subdirectory.  That process may be Python, but not necessarily.

Answer (score 5):

> the folder that i am trying to erase have some word docs that were oppened with win32com.client above in the code

That's exactly why Python throws that error. Try closing these docs before deleting the folder.

Comment: also tried to kill procces but neither works or maybe i don´t know if i killed them correctly

Comment: Try removing the lines that opens documents from the code. If the code works after that - that's the issue. Otherwise, these docs could be opened somewhere else...